# How do you determine if a PCIe device supports "ID-based ordering (IDO)" or "Relaxed ordering (RO)" in Linux

Tags: linux, network-interface, pci, amd, infiniband

[According to AMD](https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56570_0.93.pdf), a device can be prioritized on the PCIe bus if it supports IDO or RO ([which are further defined here](https://www.embedded.com/pci-express-gen-3-simplified/)). For example, an Infiniband card.

- Can you use tools like `lspci` to determine if a device supports ideal or?
- If so, how?

Comment: Do you precisely mean *"if the device supports"* (relaxed ordering) or if the device is (on the current running system) permitted to enable relaxed ordering if it is capable of ?

Comment: @MC68020, Both I suppose: It sounds like not all devices support this feature and I want to know if the device we have installed supports the feature and if it is active. Really I just want to know if the "PCIe Prioritization" feature that is presented in BIOS for the bus we have selected is active, or if it can even be activated.